# Storing a list of objects and identifying one property as a Key for fast lookup

Tags: c#, list, object, dictionary, key-value

Lets say I had a List of storyCharacter objects.  Each object stores an ID#, name, and favorite color, such as the example below:

```
ID#   |  Name        |  Favorite Color
21    |  Optimus     |  Blue
29    |  Ironhide    |  Red
34    |  Starscream  |  White
```

What would be the best way to create a a key-value pair such that it is keyed to the ID#.

I know that I could use a Dictionary, but would

```
dictionary.Add(storyCharacter1.IDnum, storyCharacter1);
```

be a good way to do it?  I assume that way would make a copy of the ID as the key, and thus use up more memory unnecessarily, since that information is already in the object.  Of course, I could just not store the IDnum in the storyCharacter object, and just use it as the key.  Since that would create an object with just the name and color, and then be associated with a key of the IDnum, that feels like I'm decoupling data that should stay together.

I could also use a List<>, but then I would have to either foreach and look through, or use LINQ.

So, is there a way to store a list (of some sort) of objects, and identify one element of that object as the key?  If not, what alternatives are there to do something similar, and what are they're tradeoffs?

Comment: How many items would be in this dictionary?  (i.e. what's the impact of 4 bytes per object?)

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Only a couple hundred, so for this project, the impact would be minimal.  I am curious of the best way to handle this if the impact was significant for a bigger dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about an in-memory datastore which is just...memory.

You ask for the "best way" of doing this but don't specify any conditions. Well, the recommended way of storing a collection of objects in memory is just to use a an array or a `List<>`. And yes, iterating through it with LINQ. LINQ is very well optimized including some run-time optimizations, it is very unlikely that your use-case is one for which this approach is too slow or uses too much memory.

If your dataset is indeed that large (in which case in-memory seems like a poor choice) and you're concerned about lookup times `Dictionary<>` is going to give you pretty solid performance.

But perhaps what you want is really something like an object database, consider [db4o](http://nuget.org/packages/db4o-devel/). Or a document database, consider [RavenDb](http://nuget.org/packages?q=ravendb) (or monogo,redis,etc) - Raven has an Embedded mode that allows you to run it in-process.

Again, for in-memory stuff this is all pedantic - against even fairly large datasets I have never seen just using the builtin `Dictionary<>` be a problem.

Comment: Part of my reticence in using LINQ is that I am pretty new to it.  Out of curiosity for future projects, if the dataset was large enough to make in-memory a bad choice, would you suggest for for performing lookup (assuming speed is the driving factor)?

Comment: @Xantham Then a properly indexed database is what you want. You don't want to hold that much data in memory. RavenDb should form the indicies for you on stuff like this. Or really just a properly designed relational database with sequential Primary Key values would work too. Oh, and don't avoid LINQ, it is - no exaggeration - the best thing about C#. Get the free version of [Linqpad](www.linqpad.net) so that you can play around with expressions easily.

Comment: Thank you for recommending that program, that does look like it may help me get a better feel for LINQ.  Since I'm still learning it, I'm just wary to use something that I don't understand all that well yet.  That and the statements used in it do appear complex for somebody new.  They may not be very complex, but they appear that way until you get used it it, it seems.

Comment: @Xantham no problem, that's what Stackoverflow is here for. As a suggestion - don't use the sql-style syntax when working with LINQ, it looks slightly cleaner initially, but in my experience the lambda syntax is far easier for people to understand what's really going on (and far more powerful as a bonus).

Answer (score 2):

Creating a dictionary like that is a common and perfectly valid way to speed up looking up something. Using more memory to gain more performance is a common trade off.

At most, the dictionary will use 8 bytes per key if IDNum is a `double` (which I doubt), other than that it will use 4 bytes per key. If IDNum is an object, it won't copy the whole object just a reference to it (which takes up 4 bytes on 32 bit systems).

But ... do you really have memory concerns? Is this on an embedded device or something with low memory? Premature optimization (for both speed and memory) is often a bad thing. I'd go with your overall design and address memory/perf issues later.

Comment: In this case, the concerns are minimal, but I thought if it was as easy as writing a List or a Dictionary, I thought I would ask to know the answer for later when I may need to work with larger datasets.

Comment: @Xantham -- it's a tough question to answer in general, because specific circumstances really affect your decision.